# Saying Hallel Before Nightfall on the First Night of Pesach

Tags: passover, zemanim, maariv, hallel

In Shulchan Oruch Orach Chayim Siman 487 Sif 4 it is brought the minhag of saying Hallel in shul the first night of Pesach

> בליל ראשון של פסח גומרים את ההלל בצבור בנעימה בברכה תחלה וסוף ובן בליל
>   שני של שני ימים טובים של גליות
>
> On the first night of Pesach, we complete the Hallel with the
>   community with a pleasant tune and a blessing at the beginning and
>   end. The same is on the second night outside Israel.

Does Hallel need to be said specifically at night? What about if a person takes on themselves yom tov early, may they say Hallel and be yotzee before nightfall? Seemingly if we consider it to be night for davening, then the same should be true for Hallel? Is there a difference?

Comment: Why would you think there is a difference? FWIW i davened early this year on the first night and we said hallel.

Comment: @Scimonster, you're right, I don't have much of a reason..Just putting it out there to see if there would be a difference, if it must be said at night.  One would have to wait until it's night to eat matzah and the arba cosos ... But maybe not Hallel (especially the hallel of Lyl Pesach which is b'Toras Shira)

Comment: @Scimonster You can't start the Seder early and Hallel is really [part of the Seder](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/70726/759); nothing to do with Maariv. I don't really see what saying Hallel too early would accomplish. Do you? Why would saying Maariv change anything?

Comment: Thank you  the answer really depends on why you say hallel @Yehoshua. There are many reasons for saying hallel and most non chasidic shuls who have only recently adopted this minhag against the r'mo say it before night.