# Can / should one praying alone recite Hallel after Arvit on the first night of Pesach?

Tags: tefilla, passover, evening-night, hallel

Many have the custom to recite Hallel in the synagogue on the first night(s) of Pesach, at the end of Arvit. (Discussed, for example, in [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70725/saying-hallel-in-shul-on-pesach-night) and its answer.)

Is this custom only to be observed in a synagogue setting? Can / should an individual praying alone (for whatever reason) also recite this Hallel after praying Arvit, before beginning his seder? If yes, does he make a blessing (assuming that he would ordinarily recite a blessing on a recitation in the synagogue)?

Comment: What's the point of saying it at davening without a blessing? None of the reasons in your linked answer apply here

Comment: @DoubleAA Is the list of reasons given in that answer exhaustive?

Answer (score 5):

R. H. Schachter rules, in a responsum found [here](https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/950285/rabbi-hershel-schachter/piskei-corona-9-hallel-on-pesach-night-and-tefillas-tal/), that this Hallel is only to be recited in a synagogue setting, as a way of publicizing the miracle of the Exodus.

As such, even if ten men pray together at home and will then all be participating in the same Seder, they should not recite Hallel after Arvit.

However, R. Asher Weiss (Minchat Asher, Leket Shi’urim uTeshuvot Iggerot uMaamarim haNoge’im leMageifat haCorona, pp. 73-74) rules that an individual with this custom should recite Hallel alone, with a blessing, before the Seder.